# How read Chrome devtools Perfomance flamechart with react_perf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I writing web application with React and Redux, and have some perfomance problem, but Chrome Perfomance User Timing and **react-addons-perf** show, that components was renreded wery quickly (0.5 - 2 ms per update tick).

React perf example:

[image: React perf]

Flamechart example with CPU 10x slowdown - very fast components rendering and slow Event (keypress):

[image: Flamechart]

In problem case i have 50-100 connected input fields, and lags when continuously pressing some button on one field.

How can i understand, where is a problem place - components rendering, Redux updates, other scripting?

UPDATE:

Connected component example:

```
class ConnectedTextField extends React.Component<IConnectedTextFieldProps, void> {
public componentWillMount() {
    this.props.validateField(this.props.modelValue.value);
}

public handleChange = (value: string) => {
    this.props.changeField(value);
};

public render() {
    const { modelValue } = this.props;

    return (
        <TextField
            value={modelValue.value}
            valid={modelValue.valid}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
    );
}
```

}

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: IStore, props: IConnectedTextFieldProps) => ({
modelValue: state.application[props.fieldReducerName],
```

});

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<{}>, props: IConnectedTextFieldProps) => ({
changeField: (value: string) => dispatch(setValueThunkActionCreator(value, props.fieldReducerName)),
validateField: (value: string) => dispatch(validateFieldThunkActionCreator(value, props.fieldReducerName)),
```

});

Simple component (only state change):

```
class ConnectedTextField extends React.Component<IConnectedTextFieldProps, any> {
public state = {
    value: '',
}

public handleChange = (value: string) => {
    this.setState({ value });
};

public render() {
    return (
        <TextField
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
    );
}
```

}

Comment: As you already mentioned and can see from the chart the keypress event chains some long time taking actions. What are you trying to do on each keypress, would it be possible to throttle/debounce the action? Is it possible to extract the problematic code part?

Comment: Add container component examples.